# How to Skip build test when running Azure DevOps Pipeline(Spring Boot Maven Project)

Tags: spring-boot, maven, azure-devops, spring-boot-test, azure-devops-pipelines

I have a problem when running Azure DevOps Pipeline.

I'm now using Spring Boot Maven Project.
I want to run Build Pipeline without building test(src/test) files,because the project will build failure with test files, and it can be built successfully without test files.

Is there any settings or configs?
Many thanks.

You can view the image to see the details, thanks.
[Please checkout the image for the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8avW.png)

Comment: post code, not pictures.

Comment: I strongly recommend to fix your tests to be building correctly. This should be the first step before any kind of build/deployment should be done...

Comment: Hi @jasonroy7dct, how are things going? Have you tried the suggestions in my answer? Is it helpful to you? Please try it. Any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 5):

The solution provided by @Bright Ran-MSFT is good but doesn't focus on the Azure Pipeline way of skipping the tests. It's because one may **NOT** want to skip the tests forever, instead just for a few temporary instances. Hence, hardcoding test skips in pom.xml may not be a good idea.
Azure Pipeline's `Maven` task provides a different way of passing the parameters.
`-Dmaven.test.skip=true` or `-DskipTests=true` can be passed through `options` argument of `Maven` task. Something like this -

```
steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: './pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'package'
    options: 'package -Dmaven.test.skip'
```

Answer (score 5):

We have the **options** argument in Maven@3 tasks that we will help to add extra command-line options for maven.

Azure DevOps Maven Tasks - [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops)

```
steps:
  - task: Maven@3
    inputs:
      mavenPomFile: './pom.xml'
      mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
      jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      publishJUnitResults: false
      testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
      goals: 'package'
      options: '-DskipTests=true'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following ways:

1. Set **`maven.test.skip=true`**

- In Terminal

```sh
mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

- Or in **pom.xml**

```xml
<project>
    <properties>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>
</project>
```

2. Use this **`-DskipTests`** in surefire plugin.

- In Terminal

```sh
mvn package -DskipTests
```

- Or in **pom.xml**

```xml
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

To view more details, you can reference to the articles below:

- [**Skipping Tests**](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/skipping-test.html)
- [**Maven – How to skip unit test**](https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-skip-maven-unit-test/)

Comment: Please do not reference such extreme old versions of maven-surefire-plugin...use the most recent ones...  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: @khmarbaise, Thanks for your tip. I have updated the version in my answer.

Comment: This worked for me:<project>
    <properties>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>
</project>